# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined -Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have written two Javascript files for nodejs application which uses express to route and for the creation of server.As i am beginner i don't know much about it.
When i am running the application,it is showing me the following error :-

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:472
    this.stack.push(layer);
              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at Function.use (/usr/lib/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:472:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dhiresh/Coding/angularjsapp/api.js:9:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dhiresh/Coding/angularjsapp/index.js:2:7)
```

index.js file is as follows :-

```
var express = require('express'),
api = require('./api'),
app=express(); 

app
.use(express.static('./public'))
.use('/api',api)
.get('*',function (req,res) {
    res.sendfile('public/index.html');
}).listen(3000);
```

api.js file is as follows :-

```
var express = require('express'),
 bourne = require('bourne'),
 bodyParser= require('body-parser'),

 db = new bourne('data.json'),

 router =express.Router(); 

 router
 .use(function(req,res,next){
    if(!req.user) req.user={ id:1 };
    next();
 })
 .use(bodyParser.json())
 .route('/contact')
 .get(function(req,res){
    db.find({userId : parseInt(req.user.id,10)},function(err,data){
        res.json(data);
    });
 })
 .post(function(req,res){
    var contact = req.body;
    contact.userId = req.user.id;

    db.insert(contact,function(err,data){
        res.json(data);
    });
 });

 router
 .param('id',function(req,res,next){
    req.dbQuery = { id:parseInt(req.params.id,10) }
 })
 .route('/contact/:id')
 .get(function(req,res){
    db.findOne(req.dbQuery,function(err,data){
        res.json(data);
    });
 })
 .put(function(req,res){
        var contact = req.body;
        delete contact.$promise;
        delete contact.$resolve;
        db.update(req.dbQuery,function(err,data){
        res.json(data[0]);
    })
    })
 .delete(function(req,res){
    db.delete(req.dbQuery,function(err,data){
        res.json(null);         
    })
 });

module.exports = router;
```

Could anyone tell me the answere for this.

Comment: bump^^ just came across this too, source is node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:502
  this.stack.push(layer);

Answer (score 89):

My problem was missing parentheses:

```
const router = require('express').Router;
```

Changing this to

```
const router = require('express').Router();
```

solved my problem.

Comment: Really, this should've been accepted because the OP never asked ES2017 import syntax

Answer (score 10):

This error occurs whenever you import Router from the Express module and then use the variable directly instead of reassigning it.

### BAD CODE

```js
import { Router as router} from express;

router.get('/', ( req, res) => {
  return res.send(req.context.models.users[req.context.me.id]);
});
```

There are other ways these bad codes could have occurred but the rule is `DON'T USE THE ROUTER VARIABLE DIRECTLY , REASSIGN IT`

## GOOD CODE

```js
import { Router as expressRouter } from 'express';

const router = expressRouter();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  return res.send(req.context.models.users[req.context.me.id]);
});
```

### OR

```js
import { Router } from 'express';

const router = Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  return res.send(req.context.models.users[req.context.me.id]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const experss = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Root route'))

module.exports = router;
```

the above code should work.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this fixes the authors problem? A code snippet which doesn't seem to relate to the questions without any explanation isn't helpful. You should [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you haven't already and improve your answer using the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)s guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```js
router = express.Router()
```

You should declare your variable with `const`:

```js
const router = express.Router()
```

Answer (score 0):

This error might be one of the following possibilities.

> Solution 1:

**Wrong-import:** `router = require('express').Router();`

**Correct-import:** `const router = require('express').Router();`
Explanation: if you import the express module with its method without the
'const' keyword; it will generate such an error

> Solution 2:

**Wrong-import:** `const router = require('express').Router;`

**Correct-import:**

```
const router = require('express').Router();
 Explanation: Importing the method Router without the parenthesis will also
 possibly generate such an error message
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `const router = express.Router();` Instead of `const router = express.Router;`